# Floating point number calculation using a 32 bit word

Tags: floating-point, computer-science

I am reading my computer organization fifth edition book by Patterson and I am confused by these two pages of text. First page:

[image]

Is the first word equal to 0.5 in decimal? I see that the sign is 0, the exponent is -1, and the fraction is 0 with an implied 1 in the significand. So 1.0_two * 2^-1 = 0.5? Is that right?

Why is 1.0 * 2^1 the "smaller binary number?". Isn't the second word bigger? It has a 0 in the sign, a 1 in the exponent, and an implied 1 in the significand = 1.0 * 2^1 = 2? Is that right?

I don't understand the paragraph that says:

> The desirable notation must therefore represent the most negative exponent as 00 ... 00_two and the most positive as 11 ... 11_two. This convention is called biased notation, with the bias being the number subtracted from the normal, unsigned representation to determine the real value.

Comment: Your confusion is due to some unfortunate wording and layout in the text. It means to say not “The value X would like the smaller binary number” but “The value X would like the smaller binary number Y”, where Y is the number in the diagram that follows. That diagram is part of the sentence.

Comment: Am I calculating the numbers right?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at them just as binary numbers, the first one is 0x7f800000 while the second is 0x00800000, so the second is a *smaller* binary number even though it represents a *larger* floating point number.  So using a binary comparison or sort would do the wrong thing.

So instead the biased representation for the exponent is used, which means the binary value for 0.5 is 0x3f000000 and the binary value for 2.0 is 0x40000000, and the binary comparison "works" for comparing and sorting floating point numbers.

The problem being that this is still a sign+magnitude representation, so you need a sign+magnitude binary comparison, while most hardware uses 2s-complement.  So you still end up needing special floating point comparison instructions/hardware.

Comment: I'm sorry what does 0x7f800000 mean?

Comment: The binary sequence of bits 01111111100000000000000000000000.  This can represent a floating point number or an integer, depending on how you interpret individual bits.